# Node-Fetch Mapping Error - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, async-await, aws-lambda

Getting an error with the "map" part when I try and run it Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

The `customers` const is declared above so not sure. Where is the undefined is coming from? Does the map need declaring?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
  ses = new AWS.SES(),
  fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(event.customer_id);

  const customers = await getCustomers();

  customers.map(async customer => await sendEmailToCustomer(customer));

  const customersEmailsPromises = customers.map(async customer => await sendEmailToCustomer(customer));

}

async function getCustomers() {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch('https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json');
    const json = await resp.json();

    return json;
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

const sendEmailToCustomer = (customer) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ses.sendEmail({
    Destination:
      { ToAddresses: [customer.email] },
    Message:
      {
        Body: { Text: { Data: `Your contact option is ${customer.customer_id}` } },
        Subject: { Data: "Your Contact Preference" }
      },
    Source: "sales@example.com"
  }, (error, result => {
    if (error) return reject(error);
    resolve(result);
    console.log(result);
  })
  );
})
```

Comment: Well that `getCustomers` call doesn't `return` anything?

Comment: Btw, you should omit that `try`/`catch` if all your handler is doing is to rethrow the exception

Comment: I'll guess you also wanted to use `return Promise.all(…)` on the result of the `map` call?

Comment: Titus answer has been added above, that "return Promise..." may be needed as it is currently returning a promise error

Comment: @Gracie are you sure the fetch returns something? can you inspect in the network panel? Also (as mentioned by others) you don't need await in front ```resp.json();``` and  ```sendEmailToCustomer(customer)```

Comment: Please use console.log(customers) before .map and we can see what return as data

Answer (score 1):

`getCustomers` doesn't return anything which means that `customers` is set to `undefined`.

Try this:

```
async function getCustomers() {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch('https://3objects.netlify.com/3objects.json');
    const json = await resp.json();

    return json;
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

You also have to return something from the function that you pass as a parameter to `.map`

```
customers.map(async customer => {
    return await sendEmailToCustomer(customer);
});
```

or just:

```
customers.map(async customer => await sendEmailToCustomer(customer));
```

And since `.map` returns a new array (does not mutate the original array), you'll have to store the return value:

```
const customersEmailsPromises = customers.map(async customer => await sendEmailToCustomer(customer));
```

Comment: …or just `customers.map(sendEmailToCustomer)`

Comment: If the array is thrown away, `.map` is useless.

Comment: I have implemented your changes into my original question what I think is the correct manner, but still getting an error. ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning```

Comment: @Gracie That is a warning not an error and it is caused because you're not calling `.catch` on a promise or adding it inside a `try catch`.