# React app shows unable to read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unable to fetch my api data but I can console and see the data.
All I'm getting is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.
Any syntax mistakes ?

This is my useEffect along with Axios get

```
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state.categories);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("admin/category")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, "data from categories");
        dispatch({
          type: actions.GET_CATEGORIES,
          payload: res.data.categories,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "error");
      });
  }, []);
```

Mapped the data in this table

```
<TableBody>
 {categories.map((item, index) =>
                    {
                     return  (
                      <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <TableRow style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                          <TableCell
                            className="contents"
                            align="left"
                            style={{
                              borderBottom: "none",
                              paddingLeft: "5%",
                              paddingBottom: "0%",
                              paddingTop: "0%",
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.name}
                          </TableCell>
```

Comment: try to set categories initial state value to [].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node-Fetch Mapping Error - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797312/node-fetch-mapping-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

`categories` will be undefined initially. One thing you can do is set a fallback to an empty array:

```
const categories = useSelector((state) => state.categories || []);
```

Or inside the store, set the initial state to an empty array as one-time centralized solution.

Comment: Thanks, this renders my screen but I can't render my data from api but i can see it when I console it why ?

Comment: Make sure the component is returning the jsx and satisfying the template of the data from the API. Are there any errors showing? Also, make sure that the store is saving the data coming. Set a console.log after the useSelector and make sure it's being updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think categories are undefined when first component is rendered. You should change the code as follows.
Added ?

```
 {categories?.map((item, index) =>
                    {
                     return  (
                      <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <TableRow style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                          <TableCell
                            className="contents"
                            align="left"
                            style={{
                              borderBottom: "none",
                              paddingLeft: "5%",
                              paddingBottom: "0%",
                              paddingTop: "0%",
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.name}
                          </TableCell>
```

Comment: Thanks, this renders my UI screen but I can't render my data from api but i can see it when I console it why ?

Comment: I think it is because your rendering is work async. you used axios , then method.

Comment: Whether you get result or not, react first tries to render the UI

Answer (score 0):

Your categories coming undefined so you need to add control when rendering it.

You can directly one control :

```
 <TableBody>
 {categories?.map((item, index) =>
                    {
                     return  (
                      <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <TableRow style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                          <TableCell
                            className="contents"
                            align="left"
                            style={{
                              borderBottom: "none",
                              paddingLeft: "5%",
                              paddingBottom: "0%",
                              paddingTop: "0%",
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.name}
                          </TableCell>
```

Or you can use if else and you can render different something :

```
 <TableBody>
         {categories && categories.length > 0 ? 
                    categories.map((item, index) =>
                            {
                             return  (
                              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                <TableRow style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                                  <TableCell
                                    className="contents"
                                    align="left"
                                    style={{
                                      borderBottom: "none",
                                      paddingLeft: "5%",
                                      paddingBottom: "0%",
                                      paddingTop: "0%",
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    {item.name}
                                  </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                         </React.Fragment>
                     ) : 
                     'Categories not found'';
```